# Using Firebase how to send a series of sensor data to the database and retrieve the keys and the values together

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project that is to send GPS points Latlng as well as data from a PM2.5 sensor to the Firebase database and retrieve them including the GPS points as well as the values so that I can plot points whose color differs according to the value of the sensor back on the map. The idea is to create a database that contains various locations with data. How could I create IDs that are the GPS points with the content that is the sensor data? And if so, how could I retrieve the value of all the and the value of  the keys so that I can finish the task. Please correct me if my fundamental idea is wrong. Any advice or tips are deeply appreciated! Thank you!

```js
  public class PMInformation {

        private int GPSLat;
        private int GPSLng;
        private int PM;

        public PMInformation(int GPSLat,int GPSLng,int PM ){
            this.GPSLat=GPSLat;
            this.GPSLng=GPSLng;
            this.PM=PM;
        }

        public int getGPSLat() {
            return GPSLat;
        }

        public void setGPSLat(int GPSLat) {
            this.GPSLat = GPSLat;
        }

        public int getGPSLng() {
            return GPSLng;
        }

        public void setGPSLng(int GPSLng) {
            this.GPSLng = GPSLng;
        }

        public int getPM() {
            return PM;
        }

        public void setPM(int pm) {
            this.PM = PM;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
      bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myRef.push().setValue(new PMInformation(100,200,50) );

            }
        });
```

Firebase database

[image]

Comment: As the picture shows. I used push() method to create a database like this. I can't fiqure out a way to get the unique IDs generated by the push() and use them to retrieve the values(GPS points and sensor data) inside. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save an entry go with something like:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
// create a key from latitude and longitude with a separator --> e.g. 100000_50000
String latLongKey = Integer.toString(lat) + "_" + Integer.toString(long);
int sensorValue = 23;
database.child("points").child(latLongKey).setValue(sensorValue);
```

This would create a database looking like:

```
{
  "points": {
    ...
    "100000_50000": 23,
    ...
  }
}
```

Obviously the longitude/latitude pair must be unique.

To retrieve the values:

```
database.child("points").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot entry: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String latLongKey = entry.getKey();
            // I won't go into the details how to extract long and lat from the string
            ...
            int sensorValue = (int) entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

I recommend [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) tutorial on working with lists of data.

**Hint:**

You use integer for longitude and latitude. Usually these values will be real numbers although you could use fixed-point numbers inside an integer I think it's usually better to use a float in that case.

Comment: If I use float, the error occurred. But if I use integer, the location is not precise... Invalid Firebase Database path: 23.6939645_120.5363532. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'  Is there possibly another solution?

Comment: A solution would be to interpret the long-lat key as a fixed-point number and omit the decimal separator. Long and latitude are values that always range between -180 and +180. The decimal separator would be always at three digits after the first number. Example: -148.847/4.8762 --> -148847_0048762. Hyphen as a minus-sign is a permitted character in keys so it's fine to use it. Write the long and lat values also as child nodes so you don't need to parse them when reading a node. Hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer met my need. Thank you very much for help!!

Comment: I have problem retrieving data

Comment: Which problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to get all those ids in order to display that data, you only need to use `getChildren()` method. Assuming that `PMdatabase` is a direct child of your Firebase root, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("PMdatabase");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int gpslat = ds.child("gpslat").getValue(Integer.class);
            int gpslng = ds.child("gpslng").getValue(Integer.class);
            int pm = ds.child("pm").getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG", gpslat + " / " + gpslng + " / " + pm);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The out will be:

```
100 / 200 / 50
100 / 200 / 50
100 / 200 / 50
//an so on
```